# Docker - duplicate mssql database

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm working with docker to test a web application, and this application needs a database. I copied my application in a `tomcat` container and created a `mssql` container.

However, I need to copy my mssql database located in a server called "tstsupsq" with all datas (not only the schema) in my mssql container.

PS : I don't have access to mdf files of the `tstsupsq` server

Do someone can help me ?

Thanks

EDIT :

After many tries, I fixed this issue with command lines.

How to copy mssql database from any server to docker with command lines :

```
sqlcmd.exe -S myServer -U myUser -P myPassword -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [databaseName] TO DISK='backupLocation\databaseName.bak'"

docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=myPassword --name containerName microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

docker cp backupLocation\databaseName.bak containerName:/var/opt/mssql/data

docker exec -it containerName /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P myPassword -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [databaseName] FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/data\databaseName.bak' WITH MOVE 'databaseName' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/databaseName.mdf', MOVE 'databaseName_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/databaseName.ldf'"
```

Your database is now avaible with all its datas in your docker container.

Comment: Not clear. What's error you get?

Comment: I don't get error, I want to duplicate a localhost database on a docker database

Comment: Show `run` command please.

Comment: docker run -d --name myDB -p 1433:1433 mssql-server-linux:latest

Comment: Now I want to copy an existing database in this server

Comment: Still not clear. Sql works but you want to restore your db?

Comment: SQL works fine, I want want to copy a database from a server to my container and I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cp` command to copy your `bak` file to `container`

```
docker cp YourDbBackup.bak YourContainer:/YourDbBackup.bak
```

Then use `SSMS` to restore `bak` file.

Comment: I used the command 'restore database PS_SHARE_QUALITY_TEST_CCA from DISK='/backup.bak' with stats=1' and obtained follwing error : Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PS_SHARE_QUALITY_TEST_CCA.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Comment: Did you copy bak file to docker?

Comment: Yes. I think this issue provides to my access rights to D:\ disk. Is it possible to create mdf and ldf files on an other disk from SQL Server Management ?

Comment: No, your script wrong. Connect your database from sql server management studio.

Comment: It perfectly works from SQL Server Management. Why did my script wrong ?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing what you do. Connect to SSMS and use wizard to restore database. It should work.